# Macro Built on PC designed to select folder. Needs to work on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, button

I've had this Macro button built. I'm getting an error immediately after pressing the button as this was designed to work on a PC.

The file is just asking for the location of the excel file to format. I just need this to work on a Mac so can someone change the code to allow opening of files from a Mac environment instead of a Windows one?

This is the Visual Basic editor;

```
Sub Johnny_Calculations()

    Dim TotalRow As String
    Dim wb As String
    Dim ws As String


    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Show
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    End With

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        Path _
        , Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier _
        :=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:= _
        True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array( _
        1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, _
        1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array _
        (15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), _
        Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    wb = ActiveWindow.Caption
    ws = ActiveSheet.Name

    TotalRow = WorksheetFunction.Match("Total", Range("A:A"), 0)

    Rows(TotalRow & ":" & TotalRow).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

       File = "Johnny Calculations.xlsm"

    Workbooks(File).Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Workbooks(File).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C22").Copy


    Windows(wb). _
        Activate
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 16.86
    Range("C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



    'calculations
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C)"
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[3])"
    Range("C7").Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R[-4]C"
    Range("C7").Select

    Range("C8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[4])/SUM('" & wb & "'!C)"
    Range("C10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[5])"


    Range("C11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[5])/SUM('" & wb & "'!C[4])"
    Range("C12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[6])/SUM('" & wb & "'!C[3])"
    Range("C13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-3]C/R[-7]C"
    Range("C15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[7])"
    Range("C16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R[-6]C"
    Range("C17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[10])"
    Range("C19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[8])"
    Range("C20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(R[-1]C/R[-5]C,""No Complaints"")"
    Range("C21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & wb & "'!C[9])"
    Range("C22").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R[-19]C"
    Range("C23").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "... so can someone change the code to allow opening of files from a Mac environment instead of a Windows one?" What have you tried so far? What line is the error occuring on? Also, you can greatly "tighten up" your code by [avoiding the use of `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Im not at all a programmer. This was something that was built for me. I get the error 'Compile Error: Named Argument not found.

Comment: what pine does it occur on? (Click "Debug" when the error window pops up)

Comment: Debug isn't an option. It just displays that error. The only thing that is highlighted when it runs (in VB) is TrailingMinusNumbers:=

Comment: If you remove that part, `, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`, does it function as you expect?

Comment: No it doesn't work by removing that. IT was designed to open a PC document. That needs changing for a Mac environment.

Comment: Try changing the `Origin:=xlWindows` to `xlMacintosh`

Comment: Nope, Same error.

Comment: Does [this page](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac015.htm) help? Or perhaps [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195814%28v=office.11%29.aspx)?